# How to select particular element in Selenium with IE Webdriver

Tags: python-2.7, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In a web page I am trying to test, I need to click on the element defined by the following:

```
<span id="mx45" class="text powerwhite goto " title="Go To ALT+G " style="display: block; cursor: pointer;" accesskey="G" mxevent="click" targetid="mx45" ev="goto" tabindex="0" ctype="label" align="middle" clicked="true">
```

I can't use the id because when the server restarts, the id changes.  I tried getting the XPATH from Firebug (as I have done for lots of other elements) but that does not get found.  All suggestions gratefully received.

EDIT
Thanks to the answers I am now able to select the element, but this has presented a new problem.  The element is a link which pops up a menu, but if I try to get Selenium to click on the link, it just flashes (like Selenium is finding it, but can't click on it).  If I click the link, my test continues, but I am struggling a bit here to make Selenium actually click the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the structure of your html,

but given, the title is unique, you could do somthing like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='Go To ALT+G ']").click()
```

you could also go for "tabindex" or "class", if your html-structure allows it.

```
someParentElement.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@tabindex='0']").click()
someParentElement.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='text powerwhite goto ']").click()
```

Which would for example be the case if you can find a parent-element below which these attributes are unique

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks like it is finding the element, but it doesn't seem to be able to click on it.  The link flashes, like Selenium keeps finding it, but just can't click on it.

Comment: if you post more html around this span element, could be that there is an actual "anchor" a-element around that you need to click instead...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the attributes I am referencing are static I would use CSS selectors referencing attributes like drkthng used

```
$$(span.text[title='Go To ALT+G ']").
```

You can also use a static neighboring element as an achor and navigate from it.

Comment: I tried this too and it works/fails in the same way @drkthng's answer did, the link flashes but never actually gets selected.